# Where are latex files when I compile a package

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-package

I am wondering why I cannot find the latex source for the manual of the 
package when it is compiled/check .

I use Rstudio to compile/check a package. There is an option 'clean up output after successfully R CMD check' that is not checked. I also use '--no-clean --with-keep.source' in R CMD check.

When I press on CHECK some files are generated in the same folder as the source files. One of them is NAME-OF-THE-PACKAGE-manual. The first line of this file is:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.5)  27 MAY 2015 13:00

entering extended mode
**C:/Users/USER_NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpq6HXud/Rd2pdf523830b237c3/Rd2.tex

that means there is a Rd2.tex latex file but  when I check the path, it does not exist.

In short: I am looking for the .tex source of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

R CMD Check is just trying to make sure it can build a reasonable PDF. If you want to make your own copy of the manual in TeX or PDF formats, there are separate R CMD entries that do just that: try `R CMD Rdconv` or `R CMD Rd2pdf`.

Reference:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/RdUtils.html